# NullPointerException errors in my Java code.

Tags: java, compilation, nullpointerexception, runtime, circular-list

Do you guys see anything wrong with my code off the top of your head:

```
/** simulates the Josephus game by killing every other person
     until the winner is the only one left.
     @return The survivor of the game
   */
 public E startJosephus() {
     E item =head.data;
     if(head.next != null){
         if(head == head.previous)
             return item;
     }
     else{
         while(count>1){
             removeAfter(head);
             head =head.next;
         }
 }
     return item;



     }
```

Here is my full code: http://pastebin.com/S0kWwFFV

Here is my driver class as well: http://pastebin.com/Nb08Dtqk

I am getting NullPointerExceptions that seem to be stemming from this method here. Please help if you see anything clearly wrong with my code.

Comment: You need to show us what line the error is occurring on.

Comment: You really need to give us more to go on here.  Your pastes are not enough to run the program, because input files, and the Student class are missing!  Furthermore, we don't really want to run the program anyways... just paste the stack trace!  Stack traces have line numbers, and we are all really super good at reading them.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't read through all your code but I found this:

```
 public void addFirst(E dataItem) {
                 Node<E> node = new Node <E>(dataItem, null, null);
                 // To be completed by the student

                 if (head == null) // list is empty
                      head = head.previous = node;

             else {
                node.next = head;
                head.previous = node;
                head = node;
             }
             count++;
     }
```

Possible culprit,

```
 if (head == null) // list is empty
           head = head.previous = node;
```

In this statement, `head.previous = node;` is being done first, but `head` is still null.  NullPointerException is being thrown ***before*** `head` is set to anything.

If head is null you definitely don't want to do head.previous

Answer (score 1):

Without more information, I'd have to guess `head` is probably null.

Comment: check my full code i posted in a pastebin link for ALL of the information